# Find users with AD property .whenCreated with less than 90 days

Tags: powershell

```
$daysOld = "-90"
$currentDate = get-date
$removeIfBefore = $currentDate.AddDays($daysOld)
$vpnuserstest = Get-ADGroupMember VPN_users -Recursive | select     samaccountname | foreach ($_.samaccountname) {
Get-ADUser $_.samaccountname -Properties samaccountname, whenCreated |
Select-Object samaccountname,@{n='Days Since Created';e={($((Get-Date)) -     $($_.WhenCreated)).Days}} |
Format-table -AutoSize}
```

Detailed Description:
I am taking the users in the group VPN_users and searching for their "samaccountname" and "whenCreated" properties. Then I would like to take today's date and go back 90 days. Anyone who's "whenCreated" date falls within that 90 day window, I want to add to a table so that I can export it later.

When I run the above code, I get everything listed as I would like, but it still includes everyone who's "whenCreated" property is above 90 days.

Sorry if the code looks "frankenstein'd" together....because it is. I took different aspects from different Google searches and threw them together.

Comment: After reading over my post, I realized that I do not have my variable $removeitBefore applied anywhere in the code. Which is why i'm not getting the results that I need. Now, i'm not sure where I could apply that in the script to get the results i'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way: Construct a timestamp-string and use with the `-LDAPFilter` parameter. Example:

```
$daysOld = 90
$timestampUTC = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysOld).ToUniversalTime()
$timestampString = "{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z}" -f $timestampUTC
Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -LDAPFilter "(whenCreated<=$timestampString)"
```

If you want to limit results to users that are a member of a particular group, you can update the LDAP query filter. Example:

```
$daysOld = 90
$timestampUTC = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysOld).ToUniversalTime()
$timestampString = "{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z}" -f $timestampUTC
Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -LDAPFilter "(&(whenCreated<=$timestampString)(memberOf=CN=Group Name,OU=Container,DC=fabrikam,DC=com))"
```

Comment: $daysOld = 90
$timestampUTC = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysOld).ToUniversalTime()
$timestampString = "{0:yyyyMMdd.0Z}" -f $timestampUTC
get-adgroupmember VPN_Users -r | select SamAccountName | ForEach     ($_.samaccountname) {
Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -LDAPFilter "(whenCreated<=$timestampString)"
         }

Comment: When I try to use it to look at the group, I get no output. Any Idea why?

Comment: Update the LDAP query to specify that you only want members of some group. See updated answer.

Comment: It still outputs everyone in the group, instead of the users that have been created within the last 90 days.

Comment: Hint: There is a comparison operator in the LDAP search filter. What would you change?